# iPhone: how to remove badge after Push Notification?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, push

What is the code to remove the badge on my app's icon? When I receive push, I need to remove it when a button is clicked!

Answer (score 97, accepted):

**objC** :

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
```

**swift** :

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
```

Comment: If your using an API like Parse.com (I was), you will likely also have to update the remote database to "0". Otherwise setting it locally will hides the badge but upon the next push the badge will not show 0 but instead show the old value +1. Like this guys saw http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13757285/clear-push-notification-badge-after-increment

Answer (score 10):

You can remove badge from push notifications by adding the following lines to your code

```
(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

As for iOS5, just setting badge number won't remove those push notification in the notification center. You have to do this...

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
```

I already tested this. It looks like `cancelAllLocalNotifications` method also works with push notifications in notification center as well.

Comment: Beware with: cancelAllLocalNotifications. The question was to remove badges from PUSH notifications but this one will remove all local notifications (is applicaiton had scheduled any).

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. But according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9925854/remove-single-remote-notification-from-notification-center , you cannot selectively remove one particular notification. You can only remove all. You should comment in Felixyz's answer too because using `applicationIconBadgeNumber=0` will also removes ALL push+local notifications, right?

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3**

```
UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
```

Can be added to following methods:

```
optional public func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool
```

and

```
optional public func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication)
```