# Reset urbanairship badge count

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

Problem:

- Let say I get 3 notification.
- It shows the badge count 3 on my app icon.
- I open the app or click on the notification and it clears the badge
  (All Good so far)
- Now when I get a new notification, the badge count shown on my app
  icon is 4 instead of 1
- That means that the badge count was not reset on Urbanairship end

My Code so far:

```
-(void)resetBadgeNotifications:(UIApplication *)application using:(NSDictionary *)notificationInfo{
    if( notificationInfo != nil ){
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"newNotification" object:notificationInfo];
    }
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber=1;
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber=0;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
    [application cancelAllLocalNotifications];
    [[UAPush shared] setBadgeNumber:1];//set to 1
    [[UAPush shared] resetBadge];//zero badge
}
```

I am calling this method from the following three places:

`didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

`didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`

`applicationDidBecomeActive`

In the last line of my function, I am clearly resetting the badge on UrbanAirship. But it seems to be not working. Can anyone please correct me if I am missing something?

Comment: I have the same problem, do you find out the solution? My workaround is to always set badget to 1 when pushing via airship.

Answer (score 1):

My original answer was for the basic push notifications offered by APNS.
I wasn't aware that UrbanAirship have a mechanism to track the badge number for each token.
Reading their documentation, it's possible that you forgot to call:

`[[UAPush shared] setAutobadgeEnabled:YES]`

> If your application uses Urban Airship’s autobadge feature, enable
>   client-side autobadge tracking in
>   application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: before changing the badge
>   value:
>
> [[UAPush shared] setAutobadgeEnabled:YES]; [[UAPush shared]
>   resetBadge];//zero badge

Comment: You mean my server should keep unread count for all the users and when a user opens the app of clicks on a notification I should reset the notification on my server, so that next time it sends from 1 again?

Comment: If that's true, what does UA's `resetBadge` method do?

Comment: @AdilMalik My mistake. I wasn't aware of the auto badge functionality on UA. See my updated answer.

Comment: thanks for investigating. But I am doing the same, still no it's not working.